# How to configure visual studio to only use the C standard library?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio

How do I configure a visual c++ project in visual studio 2019 to only use the C standard library?

I tried setting the "Ignore All Default Libraries" under the linker input settings for the project to "Yes", then under "Additional Dependencies" I added `msvcrt.lib`.

I got these errors:

```
1>msvcrt.lib(exe_main.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __seh_filter_exe 
referenced in function "int __cdecl __scrt_common_main_seh(void)" (? 
__scrt_common_main_seh@@YAHXZ)
1>msvcrt.lib(exe_main.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __set_app_type 
referenced in function "int __cdecl pre_c_initialization(void)" (?pre_c_initialization@@YAHXZ)
1>msvcrt.lib(exe_main.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___setusermatherr 
referenced in function "int __cdecl pre_c_initialization(void)" (?pre_c_initialization@@YAHXZ)
1>msvcrt.lib(exe_main.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __configure_narrow_argv 
referenced in function "int __cdecl pre_c_initialization(void)" (?pre_c_initialization@@YAHXZ)
1>msvcrt.lib(utility.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __configure_narrow_argv
1>msvcrt.lib(exe_main.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol 
__initialize_narrow_environment referenced in function "int __cdecl 
pre_c_initialization(void)" (?pre_c_initialization@@YAHXZ)
1>msvcrt.lib(utility.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol 
__initialize_narrow_environment
1>msvcrt.lib(exe_main.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol 
__get_initial_narrow_environment referenced in function "int __cdecl 
__scrt_common_main_seh(void)" (?__scrt_common_main_seh@@YAHXZ)
1>msvcrt.lib(exe_main.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __initterm referenced 
in 
function "int __cdecl __scrt_common_main_seh(void)" (?__scrt_common_main_seh@@YAHXZ)
1>msvcrt.lib(exe_main.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __initterm_e referenced 
in function "int __cdecl __scrt_common_main_seh(void)" (?__scrt_common_main_seh@@YAHXZ)
1>msvcrt.lib(exe_main.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _exit referenced in 
function "int __cdecl __scrt_common_main_seh(void)" (?__scrt_common_main_seh@@YAHXZ)
1>msvcrt.lib(exe_main.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __exit referenced in 
function "int __cdecl __scrt_common_main_seh(void)" (?__scrt_common_main_seh@@YAHXZ)
1>msvcrt.lib(exe_main.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __set_fmode referenced 
in function "int __cdecl pre_c_initialization(void)" (?pre_c_initialization@@YAHXZ)
1>msvcrt.lib(exe_main.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___p___argc referenced 
in function "int __cdecl __scrt_common_main_seh(void)" (?__scrt_common_main_seh@@YAHXZ)
1>msvcrt.lib(exe_main.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___p___argv referenced 
in function "int __cdecl __scrt_common_main_seh(void)" (?__scrt_common_main_seh@@YAHXZ)
1>msvcrt.lib(exe_main.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __cexit referenced in 
function "int __cdecl __scrt_common_main_seh(void)" (?__scrt_common_main_seh@@YAHXZ)
1>msvcrt.lib(utility.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __cexit
1>msvcrt.lib(exe_main.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __c_exit referenced in 
function "int __cdecl __scrt_common_main_seh(void)" (?__scrt_common_main_seh@@YAHXZ)
1>msvcrt.lib(exe_main.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol 
__register_thread_local_exe_atexit_callback referenced in function "int __cdecl 
__scrt_common_main_seh(void)" (?__scrt_common_main_seh@@YAHXZ)
1>msvcrt.lib(exe_main.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __configthreadlocale 
referenced in function "int __cdecl pre_c_initialization(void)" (?pre_c_initialization@@YAHXZ)
1>msvcrt.lib(exe_main.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __set_new_mode 
referenced in function "void __cdecl pre_cpp_initialization(void)" (? 
pre_cpp_initialization@@YAXXZ)
1>msvcrt.lib(exe_main.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___p__commode 
referenced 
in function "int __cdecl pre_c_initialization(void)" (?pre_c_initialization@@YAHXZ)
1>msvcrt.lib(error.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _strcpy_s referenced in 
function "void __cdecl _RTC_StackFailure(void *,char const *)" (? 
_RTC_StackFailure@@YAXPAXPBD@Z)
1>msvcrt.lib(error.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _strcat_s referenced in 
function "void __cdecl _RTC_StackFailure(void *,char const *)" (? 
_RTC_StackFailure@@YAXPAXPBD@Z)
1>msvcrt.lib(error.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___stdio_common_vsprintf_s 
referenced in function __vsprintf_s_l
1>msvcrt.lib(utility.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __seh_filter_dll 
referenced in function ___scrt_dllmain_exception_filter
1>msvcrt.lib(utility.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol 
__initialize_onexit_table 
referenced in function ___scrt_initialize_onexit_tables
1>msvcrt.lib(utility.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol 
__register_onexit_function referenced in function __onexit
1>msvcrt.lib(utility.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __execute_onexit_table 
referenced in function ___scrt_dllmain_uninitialize_c
1>msvcrt.lib(utility.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __crt_atexit referenced 
in function __onexit
1>msvcrt.lib(utility.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __crt_at_quick_exit 
referenced in function _at_quick_exit
1>msvcrt.lib(tncleanup.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol 
___std_type_info_destroy_list referenced in function "void __cdecl 
__scrt_uninitialize_type_info(void)" (?__scrt_uninitialize_type_info@@YAXXZ)
1>msvcrt.lib(default_precision.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __controlfp_s 
referenced in function __initialize_default_precision
1>msvcrt.lib(utility_desktop.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _terminate 
referenced in function ___scrt_unhandled_exception_filter@4
1>msvcrt.lib(chandler4_noexcept.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _terminate
1>msvcrt.lib(utility_desktop.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol 
___current_exception referenced in function ___scrt_unhandled_exception_filter@4
1>msvcrt.lib(chandler4_noexcept.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol 
___current_exception
1>msvcrt.lib(utility_desktop.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol 
___current_exception_context referenced in function ___scrt_unhandled_exception_filter@4
1>msvcrt.lib(chandler4_noexcept.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol 
___current_exception_context
1>msvcrt.lib(utility_desktop.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _memset 
referenced in function ___scrt_fastfail
1>msvcrt.lib(chandler4gs.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol 
__except_handler4_common referenced in function __except_handler4
1>msvcrt.lib(pdblkup.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol 
___vcrt_GetModuleFileNameW referenced in function "int __cdecl _RTC_GetSrcLine(unsigned char 
*,wchar_t *,unsigned long,int *,wchar_t *,unsigned long)" (? 
_RTC_GetSrcLine@@YAHPAEPA_WKPAH1K@Z)
1>msvcrt.lib(pdblkup.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___vcrt_LoadLibraryExW 
referenced in function "struct HINSTANCE__ * __cdecl GetPdbDllFromInstallPath(void)" (? 
GetPdbDllFromInstallPath@@YAPAUHINSTANCE__@@XZ)
```

I have also tried adding `kernel32.lib`, and `user32.lib` to the dependencies, but it shows the same errors.

Comment: Is your code C or C++?

Comment: The C runtime support library delegates/depends-on platform libraries to work.  It needs to use functionality in the platform libraries to do it's work.

Comment: Whether you are using [/MT or /MD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/md-mt-ld-use-run-time-library?view=msvc-160)?

You are telling the linker to ignore the default libraries (/NODEFAULTLIB) and link msvcrt.lib instead, which is the import library for the DLL version of the CRT.

1,Either drop the `/NODEFAULTLIB`, remove the` msvcrt.lib` and let the compiler/linker do the job.

2,Or change `msvcrt[d].lib` to `libcmt[d].lib`.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a C++ project in VS for both C and C++. It will understand both types of code. Just save your source files as .c and header files as .h instead of .cpp or .hpp. VS 2019 will automatically adjust and compile both.